# CSS psuedo classes, target first DIV .class within DIV

Tags: html, css

I thought I knew this. There's three `div`s (.service-box) inside one wrapper `div` (.p-`div`)

How do you target the first (or any.) of the three inner `div`s?

This works, shows the structure is correct, will remove all inner `div`s.

`div.p-div > div.service-box { display: none!important;}`

I just can't target the first inner `div`.

I've tried `first-child`, `nth-of-type(1)`, `nth-child(1)`

I did notice `nth-of-type(1n)` removes all inner `div`s like the first CSS line. While `nth-of-type(2n)` removes all *but* the 2nd inner `div`. Basically doing the opposite of what I would expect (apply display:none only to the 2nd `div`, leaving the others intact)

Gotta say I'm a little perplexed. Could just edit the HTML directly but.I thought we were past that you know?

Comment: Have you tried `:first-of-type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.p-div > .service-box:first-of-type {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Get a child of `.p-div` that has class `.service-box` and then select only the first child.

`.p-div` could be anything: `some-selector > .service-box:first-of-type`

CodePen: http://codepen.io/theblindprophet/pen/JKpwLk

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought..somethings up on my end. Upvote. Will close this.